# Is there a Terraform for AWS Personalize or a way to accomplish that task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-personalize

I would like to use terraform to deploy AWS Personalize, I don't see one for it on github? Does anyone have any recommendations on how to accomplish the task?

Tried running it thru a C# code but it acts up since the resources might not be ready for the next step, so I can't script out the entire thing.

Comment: Any luck? I am also looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no tools for AWS Personalize deployment. In our project we use internal tool made for that, but it still doesn't work with CD.

Since deployment of AWS Personalize with Campaign ready to use may take days, automatic tool for this probably won't appear soon.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to shed some light onto "Deployment of AWS Personalize with Campaign ready to use may take days"? Why is that so? The training time may take days?

Comment: Deploying Personalize is a little bit complicated process. You need to create Dataset and then import data into it which takes some time (depends on import size). Then you have to create Solution and train it, so it needs to create Solution Version. It takes a lot of time but still depends on dataset size. With minimal dataset size (1000 interactions) and starting from scratch, it takes around 2-3 hours to deploy Personalize. If you wish to add user or items datasets, it will take even longer.